# A way simple to resolve an domain different in my network

Tags: debian, dns, lan, dhcp, hostname

I am running a debian server in my local network. My internet-gateway is integrated in a Vodafone easybox (WLAN-)router.
To easily access my services from all my devices at every location I have an domain-name pointing to my public IP.

I am facing the problem that unfortunately the easybox from my ISP rejects requests addressed to its own public IP when they come from a LAN device. So I can access all my services from any point on earth except my own network.

What I would want to know is what is the simple but solid way to fix this? (without buying another router/gateway, also the solution should work with all my devices without having to configure special things in every device). It would be no problem to run a service like DHCP or DNS on my server, but I am not very familiar with this topic, and so the problem is that I don't know WHAT I need.

Knowing this I could search for a howTo and it will be done in a second..
So thank you for any tips or ideas on this issue!

Following some details:

- The router is a: Vodafone EasyBox 804, FW-Version CIS804-02.06. It has options for disabling its own DHCP-Server, manual DNS settings, Firewall, portforwarding etc. Only basic settings for everything.. hostname assigning isn't possible by the router (no settings for this)
- My server is running debian jessie as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Since you can access your server by hostname from outside your LAN, it sounds like you are using a public Domain Name Service to resolve your server's hostname to it's public ip address. And if your router is blocking traffic from the LAN to the server's public ip address, then try to use the router to go directly to the server's local ip address.

You should be able to edit your router's DNS settings so that you have a matching domain-name entry pointing to your server's ip address on the router's local network. Since this domain-name entry lives on your router, only computers using your router's DNS setting will connect to your server via this address. All other points on earth will use your public domain-name on your public DNS. :)

This will also save you the call out to the internet when looking for your server on the local network.

**EDIT** (router doesn't support custom internal DNS names?):

You could host your own DNS service from somewhere like [Amazon Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/). This option may take more of your time in setup and maintenance, but could be much cheaper than a new router with DNS support.

Comment: Hello Phil, thanks for your answer but sadly no, I can't set hostnames in the DNS settings of the router. The router has really only very basic settings - I don't like this, but I can't buy another one at this time.. In the DNS-Settigs of the Router I can only set DNS-Server address for primary and secondary server. It seems like there is no other way than running my own service for this?

Comment: Sorry to hear that @Kappa, I've put up and edit in case you might like to use a cloud DNS service.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed the problem by using a free CloudDNS Service
(in my case I used: https://www.cloudns.net).

#### What I did:

I simply created the following records for the domain(s) pointing to a LAN IP address like this:

- example.com  A  192.168.2.23
- cloud.example.com  CNAME example.com

Also there are nameserver records given:

- example.com  NS  ns21.cloudns.net
- (...)

In my router I changed the primary DNS server address to ns21.cloudns.net
and set the secondary to 8.8.8.8.

#### Why does it work?

Because devices on the network will use these server settings by default, when looking up a domain from inside the network. So the cloudDNS nameserver only resolves the special domains example.com and cloud.example.com - for every other domain (eg google.com) my device will look up the IP from 8.8.8.8.

(I am not sure if this is the same solution as Phil suggested, but compared with your answer the service I used was completely free and the setup only needed a few minutes. I think for a router which does not support custom DNS resolution this is quite the easiest and cheapest way :) )